# Z3 giving unexpected UNSAT for forall formulas

Tags: logic, z3, z3py, theorem-proving

I have the z3py code snippet below

```
I = Int('I')
x = Int('x')
a = Int('a')
O = Bool('O')
constraint1 = Implies(x==0,O)
constraint2 = Implies(And(x >= 6, O), x ==6)

test = And(constraint1,constraint2,(O == I <= a), I==x)
s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([x],test))
result = s.check()
print result
if result == sat:
    print s.model()
```

It needs to infer the correctness of the invariant `O` via a set of connections provided. In this case I have provided the connection `I == x` so all z3 has to do is guess the constant `a` as 6 to give to give the correct invariant of `O == (x <= 6)` which satisfies the horn clauses. However I keep getting UNSAT. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints are unsat.

You have a formula of the form Forall x . And(.... , I == x)
The last conjunction implies   Forall x . I == x, which 
is unsat because I is drawn from an infinite set of numbers, so 
it is not the case that every x in this infinite set equals I.

Comment: Yep you are right. I guess what I am trying to tell z3 to do is let it know that I is now a placeholder value for x and is being ForAll quantified over.

In other words it should read my formula as

ForAll I. And(....) from the mapping I == x

Any suggestions on how to do that would be greatly appreciated.